# PayPal Subscriptions - Tracking Refund

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm not a developer, but a project manager. So please excuse my lack of proper language.

We are trying to figure out how to handle subscription refunds and then limit account access on the site.

Here's a scenario. Member signs up for an annual subscription to gain certain capabilities in the account. 3 months into it member decides to cancel and requests a refund. Normally, if no refund is issued, subscription is good until the end of the billing period, at which point account is deactivated.

In our case, if a refund is issued, account should be deactivated immediately. Question: is it possible to set this up as part of PayPal Subscriptions? Some type of call from PayPal to our system that will trigger account deactivation.

Thank you.

Comment: You can do all this and more with IPN (Instant Payment Notification). Off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about PayPal, not computer programming.

Answer (score 0):

We recommend using IPN (Instant Payment Notifications) to be asynchronously notified of any events, in this case of those related to existing subscription/recurring payments.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/

If you enable IPN notifications you will receive a POST of PayPal in the following events (among others):

- When a recurring profile is cancelled.
- When a refund has been made to a previous completed transaction.

This way, you can set up your IPN script to keep the subscription “open” in  your side for the remainder of the month even if the profile has been cancelled, or to deactivate it if the last month has been refunded.

For more information about IPN variables:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/